# Count in where statement?

Tags: mysql

I understand the error, I have no idea how to fix this. Maybe i wrote this wrong but I should have more then 1 count? I should have a count for each url? I want to only display urls and how many times it repeated when there is more then 1.

```
mysql> select count(*) as c, url from PageInfo where c>1 group by url;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'c' in 'where clause'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about mySQL but in MSSQL I would do

```
select count(url) as c, url from PageInfo group by url having count(url) > 1;
```

so the changes are change the `count(*)` to `count(url)` and move your filter in to the `having` clause (and putting an additional count there as you can't reference the name in the select clause in the having clause).

Comment: Perfect. I never seen the having keyword. I'm running the query, its taking a bit but i believe it is correct. I'll accept when SO lets me

Comment: Weird, I got empty set whick took 7min. I know there is at least ONE duplicate here

Comment: @Scott: The move to `HAVING` is correct. But why do you suggest changing the `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(url)`? The two queries are equivalent in this case.

Comment: try running again with count(*) instead of count(url) - your duplicate might be null URLs.

Comment: @ypercube I thought that using count(*) in a select clause that also had a group by clause was not allowed. I guess I was wrong.

Comment: @Scott: The only difference is (as Dave points) if `url` has Nulls. And in some DBMS/optimizers, efficiency.